# Dynamically building a record edit form from fieldset

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform, lwc-dom, template

I am working on creating a lwc that builds a record edit for dynamically for case closure, to replace the classic functionality of the Case Close Page.

I have a simple APEX class that I can pass a fieldset name to and do a describe and get the field set members to help build what I need.

**APEX:**

```
Map<String, String> returnMap = new Map<String, String>();

//get fields from FieldSet
SObject sObj = (SObject)(Type.forName('Schema.Case')?.newInstance());
List<Schema.FieldSetMember> lstFSMember = 
    sObj?.getSObjectType()?.getDescribe()?.fieldSets.getMap().get(fieldSetName)?.getFields();
    
returnMap.put('FIELD_LIST',JSON.serialize(lstFSMember));
returnMap.put('OBJECT_LABEL', sObj?.getSObjectType()?.getDescribe()?.getLabel());
```

This returns a map containing the fields used in the fieldset.

**Response:**

```
{"OBJECT_LABEL":"Case","FIELD_LIST":"[{\"dbRequired\":false,\"fieldPath\":\"Status\",\"label\":\"Status\",\"required\":false,\"type\":\"picklist\",\"typeApex\":\"PICKLIST\"},{\"dbRequired\":false,\"fieldPath\":\"Recommended_Actions__c\",\"label\":\"Recommended Action(s)\",\"required\":false,\"type\":\"multipicklist\",\"typeApex\":\"MULTIPICKLIST\"},{\"dbRequired\":false,\"fieldPath\":\"Recommended_Actions_Other__c\",\"label\":\"Recommended Action(s) Other\",\"required\":false,\"type\":\"string\",\"typeApex\":\"STRING\"},{\"dbRequired\":false,\"fieldPath\":\"Student_Intention__c\",\"label\":\"Student's Intention\",\"required\":false,\"type\":\"picklist\",\"typeApex\":\"PICKLIST\"},{\"dbRequired\":false,\"fieldPath\":\"What_term_is_the_student_planning_to_ret__c\",\"label\":\"What term would the student return?\",\"required\":false,\"type\":\"picklist\",\"typeApex\":\"PICKLIST\"},{\"dbRequired\":false,\"fieldPath\":\"Student_Presented_Risk_for__c\",\"label\":\"Student Presented Risk for:\",\"required\":false,\"type\":\"picklist\",\"typeApex\":\"PICKLIST\"},{\"dbRequired\":false,\"fieldPath\":\"Student_Presented_Risk_for_Other__c\",\"label\":\"Student Presented Risk for  Other\",\"required\":false,\"type\":\"string\",\"typeApex\":\"STRING\"},{\"dbRequired\":false,\"fieldPath\":\"Reasons_Not_Returning__c\",\"label\":\"Reason(s) Not Returning\",\"required\":false,\"type\":\"multipicklist\",\"typeApex\":\"MULTIPICKLIST\"},{\"dbRequired\":false,\"fieldPath\":\"Reasons_Not_Returning_Other__c\",\"label\":\"Reason(s) Not Returning Other\",\"required\":false,\"type\":\"string\",\"typeApex\":\"STRING\"}]"}
```

I then have a component which iterates through each of the fields, and creates the inputs needed like so:

**LWC HTML:**

```
<lightning-record-edit-form
    object-api-name="Case"
    record-id={recordId}
>
    <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>

    <!-- For Each Input Field -->
    <template for:each={inputFields} for:item="item">
        <lightning-input-field field-name={item} name={item} key={item} id={item}>
        </lightning-input-field>
    </template>
    
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

At this point, everything is working as expected. Depending on the record type of the Case, it loads the corresponding fieldset and creates each field in my record edit form. Validation rules fire when trying to submit the form, all is good.

[image]

**Overriding the Status (Problem #1)**

I only want to show status options in the list that are of a Closed type. For example, I wouldn't want someone to be able to pick "New" or "In Progress", only options that are marked as Closed.

With how these inputs were generated, I can't think of a way to pass specific options to it. All the lightning input field knows is the `field-name`, and from there it generates it natively based on the `fieldPath` in the APEX response.

**Attempt #1:**

After I have got the data needed for building the input fields from the APEX class, I now have an array of `inputFields` that my lwc template iterates over to create the inputs. I removed the `Status` option from the array so it doesn't get built this way. Instead, I put a combo-box before my `<template for:each ...` to create this input field manually:

```
<lightning-combobox
    name="status"
    label="Status"
    placeholder="Select Status"
    value={currentCaseStatus}
    options={statusOptions}
    onchange={handleOnStatusChange}
    data-id="statusDropdown"
></lightning-combobox>
...
<template for:each={inputFields} for:item="item">
```

This allowed me to filter out the status options that specifically "Close" types.
My initial problem is solved as now my form has been generated and the status options only contain the options I want.

**My Current Issue:**

The problem I now face is that my Status input is always the first field in the record edit form, even if that is not its position in the fieldset. This is because I am not letting it be generated from the iteration, and instead creating it before the other fields, so its placement is expected.

I am trying to solve for this. I would like to be able to have the Status field in the same order it is in the fieldset. I know the position it's supposed to be in based on where the is in the fieldset, I just don't know how to move it.

I was thinking of trying to use `template.querySelector` to see if I could get the `lightning-combobox` element and move it into another position in the node tree, but not sure if thats possible?

**The Question:**

Any ideas on how I can find and move a DOM element into another position? Or, a way to remove items (non Closed statuses) from an existing combobox if I were to let it be created through my iteration approach?

**Update 1:**

Here is one solution I came up with so far. When I create my array of input fields, I conditionally check to see if we have encountered the Status field yet. If not, I push the field from the fieldset to the `Before` array. If I *have* encountered the status field, then I push the current field to the `After` array.

```
 // Map list of fields from APEX response
 listOfFields.map((element) => {
    /*
        If the current field is not Status and we have not yet encountered the Status field,
        add the field to the Before Array. If we have encountered Status field, we add this field
        to the after array.
    */
    if (element.fieldPath !== 'Status') {
        if (!hasStatusField) {
            before.push(element.fieldPath);
        } else {
            after.push(element.fieldPath);
        }
    } else {
        hasStatusField = true;
    }
    return null;
});
```

I then adjusted the template to loop over the before fields, then my status field, followed by the after fields. In theory, the Status field should now be in the same position it is in the fieldset.

```
 <!-- For Each Input Field (BEFORE Status) -->
 <template for:each={inputFieldsBefore} for:item="item">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={item} name={item} key={item} id={item}>
    </lightning-input-field>
</template>

<!-- Status Dropdown Override -->
<lightning-combobox
    name="status"
    label="Status"
    placeholder="Select Status"
    value={currentCaseStatus}
    options={statusOptions}
    onchange={handleOnStatusChange}
    data-id="statusDropdown"
></lightning-combobox>

<!-- For Each Input Field (AFTER Status) -->
<template for:each={inputFieldsAfter} for:item="item">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={item} name={item} key={item} id={item}>
    </lightning-input-field>
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @SBB.  I am trying to do something similar to what you are doing which is using field sets to populate LWC form.  Would you be willing to share the code?  Looking for how JS parses the JSON and how are you populating the HTML.  Thx